# Spacemacs - split & automatic buffer selection

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to press `SPC w /` or `SPC w s` and Spacemacs should select the new buffer and let me search for a file, simulating `SPC f f`. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to rebind those key combinations to a new command?

Comment: Yes. It can even be another trick. The important is that it works. I know I should write something in ~/.spacemacs but I don't know. So, if you have it, could you share?